# Class name not found when inheriting

Tags: c++, opencv, inheritance

I'm having a problem inheriting from a class, and looking up the error on the internet is said as being circular includes, but I'm not seeing how I'm doing it on my code.

Here is the error:

```
./src/Camera.hpp:6:40: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 class Camera : public cv::VideoCapture {
```

The class I'm inheriting from is part of OpenCV. Here is the relevant part of the code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include "Camera.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Camera camera = Camera(/*Some parameters*/);
    return 0;
}
```

Camera.hpp

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

class Camera : public cv::VideoCapture {
    public:
    Camera(/*Some parameters*/);
};
#endif
```

There are some other files included in main.cpp, but I made sure (to test) that none of them is using Camera.hpp. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Instead o posting "relevant part of the code", post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: include `highgui.hpp` if OpenCV < 3.0, or `videoio.hpp` if OpenCV >= 3.0, or simply use the include all `opencv.hpp`

Comment: @Miki, it is 3.0 but highui worked. Thanks, missed that when cleaning up the code. Thought that VideoCapture was part of core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't know `VideoCapture` is a class, maybe you haven't included the right header file.

http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.8/org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture.html suggests `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`.

Comment: Or you can include only `highgui.hpp` (or `videoio.hpp` for OpenCV 3.0).